# Meaning of "keep left"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I would like to know the meaning of the following expression:

> Keep left.

Does it mean "maintain on the left-hand-side of a road" or "do not enter"?

Comment: In countries wherein one drives on the left side of the road, and where tourism is common, "Keep left" reminds tourists from right-side-of-the-road countries that *in this country where you are now, drive in the left lane*.

Answer (score 2):

To "keep left" means to stay on the left-most lane(s) of the road.

Comment: Correct. In the United States, it's _Keep Right_. Or, in Washington State, where I live, it's _Keep Right Except To Pass_, which means to drive in the righthand lane of two lanes on a 4-lane expressway, normally. The left-hand lane is to be used only for passing slower vehicles.

Answer (score 0):

Stay on your left hand side of the road.

Answer (score 0):

It's context dependent, really.

On a straight two-lane road, the sign would mean STAY IN THE LEFT LANE. However, when you are approaching a divided road, those same words could be used to mean STAY TO THE LEFT SIDE OF THE MEDIAN (or ISLAND), like this:

[image]